# My Laravel 5.5 app not working on remote server namecheap VPS after deployment but working fine on local server with WAMP

Tags: php, laravel-5, vps

Everything about this app is working fine on my local sever, but refused to work remotely. if i visit the app www.mysite.com. It always shows internal server error. Though i don't have any route in web.php but i expected to redirect back to 404 not found page but not doing that but it does on localhost.

The other main problem is , i have many routes in **api.php**, if i send data to any of the routes, they accept data and might even save them in database where it is necessary but it will never return the json Response that i have defined after every successful operation. The response i always get is 500 internal server error even if the operation was successful. I have been on this issue for over two weeks now.

**I am using PHP 7.2 on the server**

**Here is my .htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**api.php**

```
<?php

Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'namespace' => 'User'], function () {

    Route::post('/login', 'UserAuthController@userLogin');
    Route::post('/signup', 'UserAuthController@userSignup');

});
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function userSignup(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:200',
            'password' => 'required|between:8,100|confirmed',
            'phone' => 'unique:users|required|digits:11|numeric',
            'email' => 'unique:users|required|email',

        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        $code = mt_rand(100000, 900000);
        $hCode = FacadesHash::make($code);
        if ($validator->passes()) {
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $request['name'],
                'email' => $request['email'],
                'phone' => $request['phone'],
                'otp' => $hCode,
                'password' => FacadesHash::make($request['password']),
            ]);

            $data = [
                'name' => $request['name'], 'subject' => 'Email Confirmation',
                'view' => 'mails.emailconfirm', 'code' => $code
            ];


            return response()->json(['success' => true, 'status' => 200, 'message' => 'Your account has been created successfully and an OTP code has been sent to your email'], 200);
        } else {

            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'status' => 200, 'message' => $validator->errors()->first()], 200);
        }
    }
```

the signup route for example, is working fine but will never return the Json response i specified, it will rather return 500 internal server error even if everything went well.

No error is being logged in my **storage/log** if everything went well and i dont get the response. But i do see error there if the operation was not successful.

all folders have **777** permissions and i have as well clear all caches so many times

Comment: Can you check php's error logs? Perhaps in `/var/log` unless you have a custom configuration. If you say it's sometimes executing your code but still returning a 500, then I might consider some middleware which tries to perform something after the request or maybe some events. On top there might be some php-modules missing on the server. Let's try to check if we can get a log message.

Comment: i foud the below error log where you asked me to check  [Sat Feb 22 14:37:06.006557 2020] [http:error] [pid 26129:tid 47139616982784] [c                                                                                                             lient 105.112.178.154:24113] AH02429: Response header name 'Access-Control-Allow                                                                                                             -Origin ' contains invalid characters, aborting request

Comment: Glad that I could helped. If you liked the comment - or any other comment on SO - then you can also upvote those as "helpful". You can find it on the left side, next to the comment. You will see an "upvote" icon and a "flag" icon which means you can upvote or report a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved** .  The problem happens to be my middle ware.

It was configured like the following before

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CORS
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Content-Type,X-Auth-Token,Authorization,Origin');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I now changed it to this new one below and everything started working perfectly

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CORS
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
    }
}
```